# Using get_post how could I adapt to get post via post meta? (Custom Post Type)

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have the below that grabs the post via ID. I need to alter this to use the value of a post meta item called 'reference_title'. This is a custom post type called custom_forms. I only want to retrieve 1 post in that post type

```
$post_details = get_post($post_id);
```

Thanks,

DIM3NSION

Answer (score 0):

you can use [get_post_field($field, $post_id)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field)